# Lists in Python (Using NLTK)

Tags: python, list, nltk

I'm trying to make a list of lists in the form of [[(the, cat), (cat, with), (with, fur)] [(the, dog), (dog, with), (with, ball).......etc] from a text file with the sentences in lines like:

> the cat with fur \n 
>   the dog with ball \n

The problem I've been having is that somehow while I'm reading lines in the file, word by word, making the tuples (variable label) and creating the final list (variable connection) there're empty intances were connection goes to 0. Well, not actually 0 but the list shows up like [[], [], []]

This is the code for that part of the program:
with open('corpus.txt', 'r') as f:

```
with open('corpus.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        cnt = 0
        sa = nltk.word_tokenize(line)
        label[:] = []

        for i in sa:
            words.append(i)
            if cnt>0:
                try: label +=[(prev , i)]
                except: NameError
            prev = i 
            cnt = cnt + 1

        if label != []:
            connection += [label]
            print connection
```

I hope somebody understand my problem cuz it's driving me crazy and I'm running out of time. I just wanna know what am i doing wrong here so I can update my connection list in each loop without losing what I've saved before.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Would it be safe to say that you have a list of sentences, where each sentence is represented as a list of words, and  you want to get a list of bigrams in each sentence?

Comment: Exactly, didn't know the word bigram so yea, that was easier to tell :) PS: Actually i want the bigram of all the file but separated in 'sublists' like [[(a1, a2), (a2,a3)],[(b1,b2) ,(b2,b3)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have NLTK installed, but see if this works for you:

```
with open('corpus.txt', 'r') as f:
    answer = []
    for line in f:
        cnt = 0
        sa = nltk.word_tokenize(line)
        answer.append([tuple([char, sa[i+1]]) for i,char in enumerate(sa[:-1])])
```

Comment: OMG Thanks haha that worked so well I can continue with the coding! ...10000 Thanks to you sir!

Comment: @FranciscoArriagadaArroyo: LOL! Happy to help. Good luck with the rest of your program

Answer (score 2):

You can use `nltk.bigrams` to get your tuples without worrying about getting the boundary conditions just right. If `words` is a list of the words in a sentence, you get all the bigrams with

```
bigrams = nltk.bigrams(words)
```